# building a responsive slider with flex/css and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a responsive flex slider. I have a container that is the flex and the items inside are to be centered vertically & horizontally. It's supposed to show 1 item at a time while the rest of the items are offscreen. currently it's showing all items at the same time. How do I show 1 item at a time. I can't seem to get there. If i could figure out how to show 1 main item & the rest off screen, i think i could figure the rest out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's the link to what i'm working on:

```
http://7.engineroomdm.com/exodus/home.htm
```

here's the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.dj-slider {
  background-image: url('images/slide-backgrnd.jpg');
  padding: 50px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  flexwrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.dj-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.dj-slide {}

.dj-slide:not(:first-child) {
  /*left:0;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="dj-slider">
  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="images/10-off-slide.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="images/10-off-slide.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="images/10-off-slide.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="images/10-off-slide.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE 
here's my code for trying to animate the slide:

```
<a href="#" class="dj-move-it" data-slide="1">1</a> | 
<a href="#" class="dj-move-it" data-slide="2">2</a> | 
<a href="#" class="dj-move-it" data-slide="3">3</a> | 
<a href="#" class="dj-move-it" data-slide="4">4</a>

$(function(){

  $('.dj-move-it').on('click',function(){

    var curSlide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    switch(curSlide){
      case '1':
       $('.dj-slide').css({
       transition: 'transform 0.5s',
       transform: 'translateX(0)'
       });
      break;

      case '2':
       $('.dj-slide').css({
       transition: 'transform 0.5s',
       transform: 'translateX( calc(-100% - 100px))'
       });
      break;

      case '3':
       $('.dj-slide').css({
       transition: 'transform 0.5s',
       transform: 'translateX( calc(-200% - 200px))'
       });
      break;

      case '4':
       $('.dj-slide').css({
       transition: 'transform 0.5s',
       transform: 'translateX( calc(-300% - 300px))'
       });
      break;

      default:
       $('.dj-slide').css({
       transition: 'transform 0.5s',
       transform: 'translateX(0)'
       });
    };

  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [create a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: as stated... for some reason it wasn't letting me... found a work-around

Comment: i wonder if there is a specific reason you use flex slider. i recommend using slick. it's responsive, accessible and easy to use slider.

Comment: i'm stuck in a restrictive cms :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest I can come up with is to also make each `slide` a flex container, and with that being able to center the images.

Additionally, as the `slide` elements are also flex item's, their `flex-shrink` needs to be set to `0`, or else they won't stay 100% wide.

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.dj-slider {
  background-image: url('images/slide-backgrnd.jpg');
  min-height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dj-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.dj-slide {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);    /*  added, full width - margin  */
  flex-shrink: 0;               /*  added, so it won't shrink  */
  border: 1px solid red;        /*  added, for demo purpose  */
  margin: 20px 50px;                 /*  added, instead of padding on parent  */
  
  display: flex;                /*  added  */
  align-items: center;          /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;      /*  added  */
  
  animation: slide-it 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide-it {
  0%    { transform: translateX(0); }
  25%   { transform: translateX( calc(-100% - 100px) ); }
  50%   { transform: translateX( calc(-200% - 200px) ); }
  100%  { transform: translateX( calc(-300% - 300px) ); }
}
```

```html
<div class="dj-slider">

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/f00" />
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/0f0" />
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/00f" />
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/f0f" />
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

Sample how one can click and select a slide.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var button = document.querySelector('button');

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    var slider = document.querySelector('.dj-slider');
    slider.classList.toggle('show3');

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.dj-slider {
  background-image: url('images/slide-backgrnd.jpg');
  min-height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dj-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.dj-slide {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);  /*  added, full width - margin  */
  flex-shrink: 0;             /*  added, so it won't shrink  */
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*  added, for demo purpose  */
  margin: 20px 50px;
  /*  added, instead of padding on parent  */
  display: flex;
  /*  added  */
  align-items: center;
  /*  added  */
  justify-content: center;
  /*  added  */
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(0);
}


.dj-slider.show3 .dj-slide {
  transform: translateX( calc(-200% - 200px));
}
```

```html
<div class="dj-slider">

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/f00" />
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/0f0" />
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/00f" />
  </div>

  <div class="dj-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120/f0f" />
  </div>

</div>

<button>Slide 3 - Toggle</button>
```

Comment: wow dude... that's pretty awesome. but 2 questions... css allows calc? that's new to me so if so, great! i learned something new :). 2) Will this scale down to screen size (responsive)?

Comment: @Damien 1: Yes, you've been able to do calc in CSS the last 6-7 years: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc ... 2. Yes, it scales, so you can use use percent on the elements, and the `translateX(-100%)` with percent, it is the elements own width, whatever it will be, in other words fully dynamic.

Comment: very interesting... let me give this a shot :)!

Comment: is there a reason why you changed the min-height, or is it just for demo purposes?

Comment: @Damien Changed height for demo purpose, for it to fit the snippet window w/o going to "Full page"

Comment: how would i make this work with a link? so click on 1 it goes to slide 1, click on 3 it goes to slide 3?

Comment: I've updated with code at my attempt to animate but it's not working. Seems to change the slide, but doesn't slide in (animation).

Comment: Actually... i figured it out. check it out and let me know what you think. Any other comments?

Comment: @Damien Added a 2nd sample to my answer...and yours looks similar, so no comments :)

Comment: maybe you could help with this last question... i was placing the numbers within the "dj-slider" but it doesn't have a class "dj-slide". It's not showing up under the slide... how do i get it to show under the slide so when it shrinks, it's always centered?

Comment: @Damien It sounds they are positioned absolute? .. if so, and if they were positioned _outside_ the `dj-slider`, they won't be visible as `dl-slider` has `overflow: hidden;`. If this is the case, you could either add an extra wrapper, as a child to `dj-slider`, and move `overflow: hidden;` to it, or set a bottom padding to `dj-slider`, and allow them to be _inside_

Comment: i just added another div after the last slide <div><br /><a.... 1... 2</div> i thought that would place it on the next line but nope

Comment: @Damien Nope, you can't do that w/o adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to `dj-slider`, which will cause all the `dj-slide` to wrap too...so just wrap all the `dj-slide` items and keep the number element as a sibling to that extra wrapper ... or position the number absolute at bottom, and match their height with a bottom padding on `dj-slider`